# Getting complete educations from LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to get full educations data by using the LinkedIn API but I only get the end-date and id fields as you can see.

```
[education] => Array
               (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [id] => 115254687
                            [end-date] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [year] => 2010
                                )
                        )
                )
```

I asked for the `r_fullprofile` permissions. Do I need any additional permission? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this should be fairly straightforward with the JS api: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#educations

Comment: I finally used the JS API and everything worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can post your solution as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

When you use r_fullprofile member permission, you get access to the full profile fields of ONLY the authenticated user. You can only retrieve the basic profile fields of the 1st degree connections of the authenticated user as explained in our Connections API doc. There are no member permissions that allow you to access the full profile fields of the connections. This restriction is added to protect the data privacy of users.This issue is not with your code, you are getting what our Linkedin APIs allow.

Read the following link to understand more https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

You can find a sample working JS code under following link 
http://infinityexist.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/extracting-connection-details-using-linkedin-apis-written-in-javascript/